# php array values compare

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Hi people I need your help. Let's say I have an array.

```
$arr = array(
1  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 3,           
       keyx...),
2  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 0,           
       keyx...),
3  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 2,           
       keyx...),
4  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 2,           
       keyx...),
5  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 3,           
       keyx...),
6  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 0,
       keyx),
7  => array(
       key1 => something,
       key2 => something,
       key3 => something,          
       testkey => 3,           
       keyx...),
n =>array(blabla)
)
```

I can't know how many keys $arr has.

I need to test if one or more value of testkey are equal, if they are put this result on a variable.

2 and 6 are not considered since the testkey is 0.

(0 is my default value, i can put it to NULL)

3 and 4 have the value of 1 (first to match).

1, 5 and 7 have the value of 2 (second to match).

Then I have to store this values somehow:

```
$matched = array();
    $matched[1] = array (2, 6);
    $matched[2] = array (1, 5, 7);
```

But I'm sure it can be done better.

Thank you.

Comment: 1,5 and 7 have key 3... Also 5 and 6 don't match...

Comment: If I understood You correctly You have arrays of arrays. In the second level array You have particular field ('testkey' in Your example) which You know and You want to compare against each other. Is that correct? If so You simply iterate through first array, then in the loop You access arrays with key 'testkey' and You write that result to additional (new) array as index (value of 'testkey') => value (index of first array containing the record with particular 'testkey'). Is that the case or You asked about something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would sort the array `$arr` by the `testkey` values. This can be done in O(n lg n) time.
Then you iterate through the sorted array and adds the original keys to `$matched[1]`. When the `testkey` value changes, you start adding the next key values to `$matched[2]`, etc.